# Inluding functions in header file

Tags: c++

I have header file:

dictionary.h:

```
#ifndef dictionary_h__
#define dictionary_h__

extern char *BoyerMoore_positive(char *string, int strLength);
extern char *BoyerMoore_negative(char *string, int strLength);
extern char *BoyerMoore_skip(char *string, int strLength);

#endif
```

function definations: dictionary.cpp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char *BoyerMoore_positive(char *string, int strLength)
{
} ---- //for each function
```

and main file main.cpp:

```
#include "dictionary.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"
using namespace std;
void *SocketHandler(void *);

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{ 

----

    skp = BoyerMoore_skip(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );
        if(skp != NULL)
        {
            i++;
            printf("in\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\n hi2 \n");
        str = BoyerMoore_positive(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );
        str2= BoyerMoore_negative(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );
----
}
```

When I execute main.cpp

it gives:

```
/tmp/ccNxb1ix.o: In function `SocketHandler(void*)':
LinServer.cpp:(.text+0x524): undefined reference to `BoyerMoore_skip(char*, int)'
LinServer.cpp:(.text+0x587): undefined reference to `BoyerMoore_positive(char*, int)'
LinServer.cpp:(.text+0x5bd): undefined reference to `BoyerMoore_negative(char*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I dont know why it could not find the function!
Help appreciated!

Comment: Did you pass `dictionary.o` to the linker command?

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile both source files into `main.o` and `dictionary.o` and then link these object file together into the final executable:

```
$ g++ -c main.cpp
$ g++ -c dictionary.cpp
$ g++ -o myexe main.o dictionary.o
```

Or you can build and link in one go:

```
$ g++ -o myexe main.cpp dictionary.cpp
```

You'd normally create a `Makefile` to take the drudgery out of this process, which might be as little as (untested):

```
myexe: main.o dictionary.o
```

Then it's simply:

```
$ make
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was missing dictionary.cpp in compilation!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your `dictionary.cpp` is included to your project and built without errors?
Linker can't find those functions in object-files after compilation, check out full log for compilation error or success of your `dictionary.cpp` file.